# TF2 wants to download an 4 gig update file

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I recently had an bad shutdown and had to run chkdsk. When I ran Tf2 again, Steam started to verify the cache files. After that it now wants to download a freaking 4.3 gig update(WTF).

I had already downloaded the [latest patch](http://www.steampowered.com/platform/update_history/index.php?id=440).

[image]

Why the hell is this happening and can i restore a tf2 backup to prevent the redownload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes if your files get fragmented or corrupted in some way, steam will try to validate your cache and see if all your files are intact (this could have been caused by your shutdown). It looks like in your case you have to download a large part of the cache again. All this replaces though is core game files - if you have any skins, mods, etc. they will be fine as they are separate from the actual game. I would just let this redownload as it should have no negative repercussions.

Comment: Once it's finished, make a backup eh? ;p

Comment: Downloading 4 gigs takes a long time, i have a 4 month old backup, can I use it ?

Comment: @HackToHell - You can try a backup.  You still will have to download any updates.

Comment: It would have to a back up of your GCF, and you will have to validate and update it again. It might make the process quicker.